# How to enable libreoffice presentation console on Libreoffice Impress?

Tags: 11.04, libreoffice

Yesterday i browse on synaptic and found this extension

> libreoffice-presenter-console

i found this extension very helpful for me in my presentation in front of my class

so i installed it, but i don't know how to enable this feature it is there anyone know ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just installed it, started up Impress and started a slideshow and it showed up on my other monitor like this:

[image: Presenter Console]

Do you have two screens plugged in?

Comment: i use lcd projector, and nothing happen

Comment: Have you got it set up to span your desktop? You should be in a position where you have you see different things on the screen and the projector. You might need to play with the Monitor settings dialogue.

Comment: Just for the record: I find that the presentation console does not work when using NVidia's TwinView feature to drive two monitors because this represents only one huge screen to xorg applications, so LibreOffice doesn't "notice" the second screen.

Comment: @jstarek The screenshot I took was using TwinView. TwinView *is* one X screen but it does provide monitors hints so applications and the desktop compositor can work out how to place things.

Comment: @Oli, thanks for the correction. I'll remove my comment in order not to confuse search engine users, although I can not get the presentation console to work on my TwinView setup. But this is a different discussion.